# Getting ownProps in a custom React HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm implementing an HOC that needs access to the props of the component being wrapped. This would work in a similar way to how react-redux implements `ownProps` in `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

> ***Note***: I am looking for a way to get the props being passed into a custom HOC, ***NOT*** how to use react-redux. I am only mentioning react-redux to illustrate my use case

I would like to do something like this: (note that this example will not work)

```js
const HOC = InnerComponent => {
  console.log(InnerComponent.props.SomeProp)
  return InnerComponent
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The props you pass to `InnerComponent` are first passed through the HOC as `this.props`. So if your HOC is a class component, you should have access to the props being passed to `InnerComponent` as well.

```
const HOC = InnerComponent => {
    return class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            // You should see all props passed to InnerComponent here
            console.log(this.props);
            return <InnerComponent {...this.props} /> 
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Chase answered what OP actually asked, even though it was marked as the accepted answer.

The redux `connect` function [is a higher-order function](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-maximizing-composability) that returns a HOC. `connect` Takes a `mapStateToProps` function as an argument. The `mapStateToProps` also takes the ownProps of the Component that is being wrapped as an argument. I think what OP asked is how to do that.

Here's how I've build the `withSomething` function that operates like the `connect` function with regards to using ownProps.

```
// withSomething function takes a function
export const withSomething = mapOwnPropsToSomethingProps =>
    // ...and returns a higher-order component
    WrappedComponent => {
        // ...that returns another component...
        return function ComponentWithSomething(props) {
            // ... that renders the wrapped component with Something
            // that receives the mapped somethingProps
            const somethingProps = mapOwnPropsToSomethingProps(ownProps);
            return (
                <Something {...somethingProps}>
                    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
                </Something>
            );
        };
    };
```

Here's how to use the `withSomething` function:

```
const enhancedComponent = withSomething(ownProps => ({
    myId: ownProps.id,
}))(MyComponent);
```